# Overzealous question ban algorithm?

Tags: discussion, questions, post-ban

I was about to ask my third question here and got the belowmentioned warning. My two questions were not even particularly unsuitable. Was the QB bot acting overzealous, since it was a small sample size and the only "violation" happened a while back?

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Comment: did you check recent deleted questions, as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)? "deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 90 days, can be seen using..."

Comment: Questions like these should be posted on Meta. The guidelines on what is and is not acceptable are quite clear. No legal, commercial or career questions. All questions should have specific answers not based on opinions et. etc.

Answer (score 4):

You've asked more than 3 questions here. You have asked a total of [8 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/29430/aitchnyu?tab=questions). Of these 8 questions, a total of 4 have a negative score and 1 has a neutral score. Your overall net score on questions is -3. In addition, 4 questions were closed (including some of the deleted ones) and 2 were migrated. This does indeed warrant the automatic quality messages.

Answer (score 3):

> My two questions were not even particularly unsuitable

Your latest question is a legal question, and therefore unsuitable. Your previous questions also have quality problems (read the comments there for more information).

This leads me to believe that the bot is not acting overzealous, and that the warning it issued was justified.